# geometry() in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am a beginner for GEE. I don't understand about "geometry". What's the difference between `var studyRegion = roi.geometry();`and `var studyRegion = roi;`[image]?

Comment: `roi` is probably an object having a `geometry` property (+some others) so when assigning it to your var `studyRegion` you assign all the content of that object to your variable, and if you precise that you only want the `geometry` property, well, you only get the `geometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table or feature collection (`ee.FeatureCollection`) is a collection of features (`ee.Feature`). A feature has a geometry (`ee.Geometry`) and properties.

If you print a `ee.Feature` you'll see:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12.3456,
              -6.54321
            ], ....
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "00001",
      "properties": {
        "id": 0,
        "area": 1234,
        ....
      }
    }
```

Your `roi` is a table, so it has one or many `ee.Feature`. When you call `roi.geometry()` you get all the geometries (of all features) merged together. A simple example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ae458356e23340a09d46e5fb5584b9df

Many functions into GEE need a `ee.Geometry` as a parameter